# convert the string to date

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb6

this is for my VB.Net project. In this phase i am pulling data from excel to VS2010.

In this i have the date in string format 25.10.2013, I want to add this date in datagrid but it is showing "Conversion from string "" 25.10.2013" to type 'Date' is not valid" error.

Please check both the below codings (Function & While) and provide me the solution to fix this.

```
If DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
  Try
    Dim objreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenDLG.FileName)
    linecount = 0
    dupord = 0
    nooford = 0

    While Not objreader.EndOfStream
        fallout = objreader.ReadLine
        If linecount >= 0 Then
          If fallout = "" Then
              Exit While
          End If
        ' Dim tmpArray() As String = Regex.Split(Trim(velocityfallout), " ")
          Dim tmpArray() As String = Regex.Split(Trim(fallout), ",")
          If tmpArray(0) = "" Then
            Exit While
          End If
          pono = tmpArray(0)
          issue = tmpArray(1)
          falldate = getToday(tmpArray(3))
          ftype = "Velocity"
          checkfallout("Velocity", "", "", falldate, "", pono, "", issue, "")
          nooford = nooford + 1

       End If
      linecount += 1
    End While
```

GetToday Function :

```
Function getToday(ByVal dateStr As Date) As String

    Dim dateStrRet As String

    dateStrRet = CStr(DatePart("yyyy", dateStr)) & "-"

    If DatePart("m", dateStr) < 10 Then
        dateStrRet = dateStrRet & "0" & CStr(DatePart("m", dateStr)) & "-"
    Else
        dateStrRet = dateStrRet & CStr(DatePart("m", dateStr)) & "-"
    End If

    If DatePart("d", dateStr) < 10 Then
        dateStrRet = dateStrRet & "0" & CStr(DatePart("d", dateStr))
    Else
        dateStrRet = dateStrRet & CStr(DatePart("d", dateStr))
    End If

    Return dateStrRet
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the method `getToday` should return the date-string for today, you get it via `Date.Today.ToShortDateString` or `Date.Today.ToString("d")`.  But if you want it to be in a specific format, for example with english or german date separator, you have to provide an appropriate `IFormatProvider`. The german culture `"de-DE"` is for example using `.` as date separator:

```
'fallback culture
Private Shared ReadOnly deCulture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")

Function getToday(ByVal dt As Date, Optional provider As IFormatProvider = Nothing) As String
    ' force culture "de-DE" (germany) if no one was provided:
    If provider Is Nothing Then provider = deCulture
    Return dt.ToString("d", provider)
End Function
```

Since it's not that clear, maybe you have also problems to parse the date from the string. Then you have to use `Date.Parse` or `Date.ParseExact` (or the `TryParse` methods) with the appropriate culture:

```
Dim dateStr As String = tmpArray(3)
Dim deCulture As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")
Dim dt As Date
If Date.TryParse(dateStr, deCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    dateStr = getToday(dt, deCulture) ' you can omit deCulture since that is default here
End If
```